# "an einem Projekt arbeiten" oder "in einem Projekt arbeiten"?

Tags: phrase, standard-german

Mir kam diese Frage in den Sinn, als ich einem Personalvermittler antworten wollte.

Ich habe mal gegoogelt, und den Zahlen nach scheint *an einem Projekt arbeiten* deutlich öfter benutzt zu werden als *in einem Projekt arbeiten*.

Hätte jemand eine gute Erklärung welcher Ausdruck sprachlich (eher) korrekt wäre? Lässt sich dies grammatikalisch erklären oder hängt das von einer *Deutungshoheit* (wer oder was auch immer es ist) ab?

---

I stumbled upon this one when writing an answer to a recruiter.
I am a German native speaker but could not really explain this to myself.

I tried to count via Google and it seems that *an einem Projekt arbeiten* is more widely used than *in einem Projekt arbeiten*.

Could someone explain which one is correct according to current German grammar or language theory ?

Comment: Du kannst Fragen hier auch auf Deutsch stellen.

Comment: Ich stelle es mir schwierig, **in** etwas anderem als einem Gebäude, Fahrzeug etc. zu arbeiten. *Ich arbeite **in** einem Projekt.* würde ich so verstehen, dass jemand in einer ewigen Baustelle arbeitet, oder in einem architektonischen "Kunstwerk".

Comment: @Janka: Das sehe ich anders. Zumindest in meinem Bereich (Wissenschaftsbetrieb) sind die Formulierungen "Ich bin **im** Projekt X angestellt" oder "Ich arbeite **in** dem Projekt X über das Thema Y" völlig gang und gäbe. Dabei geht es um Forschungs- oder Entwicklungsprojekte, also nicht um ortsbezogene Dinge, **in** denen man arbeiten kann.

Comment: @Elyasin: Meiner Meinung nach ist das eine philosophische Frage, aber keine, die explizit mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat. Das Problem besteht nämlich in mehreren Sprachen: vgl. "I work **in** / **on** a project".

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach sind beide Varianten möglich, haben aber eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung. "An" ist für mich eher ein kleines Projekt, an dem ich alleine arbeite, "in" hingegen ein großes Projekt, an dem mehrere Personen mitarbeiten.

Comment: @IQV Dies wäre auch die Richtung meiner Meinung, aber meine Suche zeigte mir, dass es nicht alle so sehen oder verwenden.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Da sind wir uns auch nicht im Klaren. Mein Kumpel besteht auf *on a project*, aber das ist auch nicht so einfach zu erklären. Siehe https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83442/what-is-the-difference-between-i-work-in-a-project-vs-i-work-on-a-project (es scheint, dass das Interesse auch nicht so gross ist). Vielleicht ist die Frage wirklich nur theoretisch Interessant.

Comment: ... oder mangels eindeutiger Regelungen einfach eine Entscheidung nach dem eigenen Sprachgefühl.

Comment: @IQV: Auch alleine kann man an einem großen und in Gruppn in einem kleinen Projekt arbeiten. Ich stimme aber zu, dass man, sofern man alleine am Projekt arbeitet, auf "in" eher verzichten wird. Bei mehreren Leuten ist man aber frei beide Formulierungen zu nutzen.

Answer (score 2):

"Ich arbeite an X" sagt aus, dass ich einen Beitrag zu X leiste.

"Ich arbeite in X" beschreibt meinen Arbeitsort. Es beschreibt nicht, was ich eigentlich tue. Üblicherweise ist *arbeiten in* auch ein *arbeiten an*, aber es gibt Sondersituationen, wo das nicht das gleiche ist; z.B. könnte ein Journalist *in* einem Projekt arbeiten aber nicht *am* Projekt, sondern er arbeitet am Artikel, den er über die Projektgruppe veröffentlichen will.